# Ошибка при использовании input в emacs

Tags: python, python-3.x, emacs

Настроил emacs как IDE для Python. В итоге всё работает, всё отлично, кроме одного "НО". При если я использую команду input в программе на Python и запускаю свой код, то выдаёт ошибку.
Вот пример программы:

> print ('Hello, World!!!')
>   name = input('Say me your name, please:')
>   print(f'Hello, {name}!!!')

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
Hello, World!!!                                                                                                                       
Say me your name, please:Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                           
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Если пишу вместо второй строчки:

> name = 'Sergey'

то всё работает нормально.

Вот кусок .emacs, который касается работы с Python:

> ;; Для запуска в Python режиме будет использоваться комбинация C-c e
>   (defun eval-python-buffer ()
>   "Execute current buffer as Python code."
>   (interactive)
>   (shell-command-on-region 1 (point-max) "/usr/local/bin/python3"))
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'eval-python-buffer)

В обычной консольке конечно же всё работает и для этого необходимо запускать программу отдельно от emacs. Но хочется как-то "по нормальному".
Как сделать, чтобы input полноценно работала?
lisp знаю пока очень плохо, пока еще даже не изучал как следует, данный кусок кода скоммуниздил откуда-то с просторов Интернета.
Заранее спасибо всем тем, кто откликнулся на этот вопрос!